# Автозапуск программ. Откуда берутся имена в диспетчере задач?

Tags: c#, автозагрузка

Прописываю, допустим, такой код:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey myKey Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWAREMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionRun", true);
myKey.SetValue("MyProgram", Application.ExecutablePath);
```

В списке "Автозагрузка" диспетчера задач получаю имя программы не `Program.exe`, а название, которое я указывал при создании проекта в `Visual Studio`. Как изменить название программы так, что бы в списке автозагрузки оно отображалось?

Answer (score 0):

вы можете как угодно переименовать файл, процесс .net-приложения, при запуске, получит имя запускаемого модуля, заданное при компиляции.

Таким образом, чтобы переименовать ваше приложение в диспетчере задач, придется перекомпилировать его, указав в настройках проекта желаемое имя.